# circleci deployment to heroku failed on git push

Tags: git, heroku, circleci

I just set up a new project to deploy to heroku from circleci. I have my build script as follows:

```
git push git@heroku.com:socialjusticebingo.git $CIRCLE_SHA1:refs/heads/master
```

In the console from my circleci build I see the following:

```
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To git@heroku.com:socialjusticebingo.git
 ! [remote rejected] ca5c72a28f7ca9c793becd122e6bc73bf8f34b44 -> master (missing necessary objects)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently this issue is related to shallow clones. I was able to get past the issue by altering my deployment script to read as follows:

```
git fetch origin --unshallow
git push git@heroku.com:socialjusticebingo.git $CIRCLE_SHA1:refs/heads/master
```